# Inverse function of a polynomial complex function

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers, inverse-function

Let $z,w\in\mathbb{C}$ be complex variables and define the function $f:w\mapsto z$ given by
\begin{align}
z=w+ aw^2+bw\bar{w}+c\bar{w}^2,
\end{align}
where $a,b,c\in\mathbb{C}$ are complex constants. What is the inverse function $f^{-1}:z\mapsto w\:$?
I am not very familiar with complex analysis, so I greatly appreciate any comment or response.

**Note 1:** We can assume that the function is invertible, so we do not need to worry about the invertibility.

**Note 2:** I am reading a textbook that claims that the inverse function is 
\begin{align}
w=z - az^2 - bz\bar{z}-c\bar{z}^2 + O(|z|^3),
\end{align}
and no more information is given.

Comment: Why do you think that this function has an inverse?

Comment: You mean $f:w\mapsto z$?

Comment: @rschwieb Yes. Sorry for the typo. I revised it.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I am reading an ODE book, where the author has claimed that this function has an inverse. Moreover, If $z,w\in\mathbb{R}$, then this function is invertible (at least in some interval).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

The given function can be decomposed in the form of a system of real equations
$$u=P(x,y),\\v=Q(x,y)$$

where $P,Q$ are bivariate quadratic polynomials.

When you vary $u$ and $v$, you obtain pencils of conics. Hence the solutions in $x,y$ are formed by the intersections of two conics, and this leads to a quartic equation, having up to four distinct solutions.

There is a (complicated) analytical solution, and you will have to select branches...

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is it possible to say that the inverse function has a general form, for instance $w=z-az^2-bz\bar{z}-c\bar{z}^2+O(|z|^3)$? This is all that is mentioned in the textbook that I am reading, but I cannot justify it.

Comment: @Arthur You should have asked this question directly, it is a very different one.

Comment: Sorry about that. I will edit the question.